# Chase camera with sprite in andengine

Tags: android, camera, sprite, andengine

ı have created a race game and the camera follow the car with code below.Besides there is a sprite in scene which is in (100px,100px) as button.the problem is: When camera moves, the button never move.The button must always show on screen.But it don't move.What can I do?

```
mCamera.setChaseEntity(sprite);
```

Answer (score 8):

Use HUD. It is a special Scene that does not move when the Camera moves and it was created for exactly this purpose. The basic usage looks something like this:

```
private HUD mHUD;
mHUD = new HUD();
camera.setHUD(mHUD);
mHUD.attachChild(button);
```

Comment: it works well but  have a new problem.When i wanna add two button,one of them isn't visible.only the second one is visible.

Comment: you can do that like JohnEye sayed:

Comment: `mHUD.attachChild(button1);`
`mHUD.attachChild(button2);`
And don't forget to register the touchAreas of each button to the HUD. The big difference to your normal scene and this HUD is, that everything you add to the HUD is placed on a relative position on your camera and not on your scene. So maybe your two buttons where just overlapping ? Try to set another position for the second button. like: 
`button1.setPosition(0,0);`
`button2.setPosition(0,button1.getHeight());`

Answer (score 0):

Either tell the button to move when you move the camera. (not recommended)
OR
Have the button on a layer above the camera view, so it independent of the camera movements.

Comment: I tried telling move to button but it's not good..How can I do another choice? can you give me code piece,plz?